# Highlight the Selected LinkButton Inside List View

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, highlight

In asp.net C# webform Have a list view with one button after binding it convert to many buttons  dynamically want to highlight selected button

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewCompanyServicesList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder" OnItemCommand="ListViewCompanyServicesList_ItemCommand">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    </div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnTags" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>' CommandName="SelectService" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ServiceId") %>' CssClass="label label-default" Style="display: inline-block" OnClick="btnTags_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <div class="promote_contentBox2">
      <p class="well" style="font-size: 80%;">No record Found</p>
    </div>
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What does `selected linkbutton` means here? As far i know, link buttons are like clickable `link`, nothing can be selected here!

Comment: I have Button A in List View When ListView is Bind then its has Buttons Like A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6. When Clicked on A2 the Color of A2 Should Change then when Clicked on A3 the A2 color should rest to default and A3 should be highlighted

Comment: Then you can do it using simple css like this `a[id*='btnTags']:visited { color:#CCC; }` replace #ccc with required . It says if there is any id containing `btnTags` ( like A1, A2 etc..), if that link is visited, then CSS will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css of the button that has been clicked.
btnTags.CssClass="your custom class";

Comment: I have Button A in List View When ListView is Bind then its has Buttons Like A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6. When Clicked on A2 the Color of A2 Should Change then when Clicked on A3 the A2 color should rest to default and A3 should be highlighted